# gcc cannot find _start

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, x86-64

When compiling the code below with

```
gcc -nostdlib main.cpp
```

I get the following error

```
/usr/bin/ld: warning: cannot find entry symbol _start; defaulting to 0000000000001000
```

I don't understand why the linker can find my _start function. I've seen examples online where people seem to be defining _start like below or defining it in assembly. What am I missing?

main.cpp:

```
int main() {
   return 0;
}

void _start()
{
   main();
}
```

Comment: C++ does name mangling, so the name in the object file is not just `_start`.

Comment: Try declaring it as `extern "C"` to prevent mangling.

Comment: That was it,Thanks! If you make an answer I'll accept it.